# 64 to 32 - 64bit in Ubuntu (19.04)

Tags: 19.04

Trying to install iTunes on Ubuntu, 
I changed my 64bit system  to 32bit with a command in terminal, 
how do I convert it back to 64bit?
I can't find instructions anywhere?

Comment: You cannot change from 64bit to 32bit with a command, it requires a re-install.  You probably just added x86 (32bit architecture) to your x86_64 bit (64bit) machine.

Answer (score 2):

Your installation of Ubuntu cannot be changed from one architecture to another via a single command, that sort of thing requires a full re-installation. If your install started as 64-bit, then it is still 64-bit.

If you added a 32-bit repository to your software sources, then you don't need to make any further changes.

Comment: Additionally, 19.04 is not available in 32 bit versions

Comment: @CharlesGreen I actually didn't know that! I haven't bothered with 32-bit installs for years.

Comment: The latest Ubuntu with 32 bit I can find is 16.04